# While Convert time to decimal output varies in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried below query to convert time to decimal but output varies

```
SELECT
    in_time, out_time,  
    DATEDIFF(second, in_time, out_time) / 3600.0,
    TotalHrs 
FROM
    table
```

Results:

```
    in_time                       out_time              (Vary output)      TotalHrs
    2018-10-19 07:18:54.000     2018-10-19 19:03:06.000     11.736666          11:44:12.0000000
```

Expected output:

```
11:44 as decimal
```

I want to calculate time with some numbers

```
 11:44 * 50
```

Comment: 0.7366 * 60 = 44 minutes only. remember that there are 60 minutes in an hour; not 100

Comment: mysql and sql-server are different databases

Comment: You convert the time to seconds, perform the calculations, convert seconds back to time.

Comment: can u please tell how?

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags, pls add the one back that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
 cast (RTRIM(DATEDIFF(second, in_time, out_time)/3600)+'.'
+ RIGHT('0'+RTRIM((DATEDIFF(second, in_time, out_time) % 3600)/60),2)as numeric(18,2))
```

And also u can able to calculate with this

```
 cast (RTRIM(DATEDIFF(second, in_time, out_time)/3600)+'.'
    + RIGHT('0'+RTRIM((DATEDIFF(second, in_time, out_time) % 3600)/60),2)as numeric(18,2)) * 50
```

OUTPUT:

> 11.44

Answer (score 0):

In **MySQL** (question [originally tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52913038/1) as MySQL), you can use [`TimeDiff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function, to get difference between two [MySQL Datetime format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) values (`'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`), and get **output as MySQL datetime format**.

Try:

```
select in_time,
       out_time, 
       TIMEDIFF(out_time, in_time),
       TotalHrs 
from table
```

**DEMO:**

```
SELECT timediff('2018-10-19 19:03:06.000','2018-10-19 07:18:54.000');

+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| timediff('2018-10-19 19:03:06.000','2018-10-19 07:18:54.000') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 11:44:12.000                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```